# thrust doesn't provided the expected result using thrust::minimum

Tags: cuda, thrust

consider the following code, when p is a pointer allocated GPU-side.

```
thrust::device_ptr<float> pWrapper(p);
thrust::device_ptr<float> fDevPos = thrust::min_element(pWrapper, pWrapper + MAXX * MAXY, thrust::minimum<float>());
fRes = *fDevPos;
*fDicVal = fRes;
```

after applying the same thing on cpu side.

```
float *hVec = new float[MAXX * MAXY];
    cudaMemcpy(hVec, p, MAXX*MAXY*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    float min = 999;
    int index = -1;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < MAXX* MAXY; i++)
    {
        if(min > hVec[i])
        {
            min = hVec[i];
            index = i;
        }
    }
    printf("index :%d a wrapper : %f, as vectorDevice : %f\n",index, fRes, min);
        delete hVec;
```

i get that min != fRes. what am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`thrust::minimum_element` requires the user to supply a comparison predicate. That is, a function which answers the yes-or-no question "is `x` smaller than `y`?"

`thrust::minimum` is not a predicate; it answers the question "which of `x` or `y` is smaller?".

To find the smallest element using `minimum_element`, pass the `thrust::less` predicate:

```
ptr_to_smallest_value = thrust::min_element(first, last, thrust::less<T>());
```

Alternatively, don't pass anything. `thrust::less` is the default:

```
ptr_to_smallest_value = thrust::min_element(first, last);
```

If all you're interested in is the *value* of the smallest element (not an *iterator* pointing to the smallest element), you can combine `thrust::minimum` with `thrust::reduce`:

```
smallest_value = thrust::reduce(first, last, std::numeric_limits<T>::max(), thrust::minimum<T>());
```

Comment: and which way is faster? i used the way you wrote me last night and it returned a pointer (device_ptr). on which i had to use the * operator to extract the value.

Comment: They should be nearly the same speed as they're both limited by bandwidth of reading the array.